# Partition File in Java(without reading the entire file) (split command)

Tags: java, unix

I am trying to divide a big file using Java. Is there a way to divide a file and create smaller chunks without reading the entire file? I can calculate the points in the file where it should be splitted.

Does anyone know how the split command(unix) does it?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do so without reading each line in the file at least once. See the link posted by @reto for a good solution.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 yes I know the solution to read the entire file, thats what I am trying to avoid. Does anyone knows if the split command reads the entire file to split it?

Answer (score 0):

You need [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), it can reads file by bytes , so you could do stream-like processing.

Thought `RandomAccessFile` is quite easy to use, but it turns out pretty slow for big files. The reason is, it needs to interactive with disk every time it reads something, that will make a lot of data copies.

If you need to speed it up, you can use `MappedByteBuffer` and `FileChannel` as an alternative.